What is the difference between the usage of present perfect and past simple in "It's not that I did, but I have" in this context
I was watching an American gamer Gino streaming his gameplay on Twitch.com and one of the people watching him said in the viewer's chat "Gino did PvP" (PvP stands for "Player vs Player" and it's a game mode in which you fight other players in this very game. Most of the game is a single player experience though.) Gino noticed that statement in the chat and answered:

It's not that I did but I have. That's the better way of putting it. But I don't PvP.

I feel like this contradicts this explanation from Britannica's dictionary about the differences between the past simple and present perfect tenses:

Use the simple past when the action started in the past, finished in the past, and is not continuing now. Use the present perfect when the action started in the past and is continuing now.
The simple past tells us that an action happened at a certain time in the past, and is not continuing anymore. It doesn't tell us anything about when an action happened, so more information needs to be given with this verb form, such as when the action took place.
The present perfect tells us that an action started in the past and it is still happening now, or it is something that happens regularly. We may need more information to tell us how long it has been going on. It may also tell us that the time period it started in is still going on.

Based on this, wouldn't "I have done PvP" mean that he still does PvP? I admit that by feeling I somehow know that what he's saying is correct but it seems at odds with what the Britannica is teaching.
Can you verbalize what kind of a rule applies here that makes it correct?

I'd guess that It's not that I did but I have is someone's clumsy shortening of It's not true that I engaged in PvP on this occasion, but I admit that I have done PvP [on one or more other occasions] in the past. It's poor phrasing, and I don't think you have anything to gain by studying it, except as a warning to avoid such terseness in your own speech.

Use the present perfect when the action started in the past and is continuing now.=NO. The action is not continuing necessarily at all. Present perfect signals the past without specification of when it was. Sometimes, an action can continue but not always (I've been working at that company) but not "I've been to Rome but not recently." The past without specification is the least understood of all the uses of the present perfect. It can just mean "in the past".

Bear in mind that a chat session on twitch.com does not constitute a reliable source of examples to improve one’s English.

I may be wrong here, since I'm not familiar with the context other than what you've posted in the question, but here is my best guess: Gino isn't using "did" as a past-tense marker auxiliary verb, but instead as a main verb, using a colloquial definition of "do" meaning 'specialize in.' So, when he says "It's not that I did, but I have," the contrast isn't meant to be one of tense (past vs. present perfect), but of semantics. As in, "No, I didn't "do" PvP (as in, specialize in producing this type of content), but I have "done" it (as in, played competitively on specific occasions)

What @PaulTanenbaum said, and in particular, if he's saying this while playing a game, his brain is mostly focusing on the game, so he's likely to say things incorrectly. Treat it as a mistake. There's nothing to learn from it.

The passage that you quote is a bit confusingly presented IMHO, but the relevant bits are this:

[…] more information needs to be given with [the simple past], such as when the action took place.

and this:

[The present perfect] may also tell us that the time period it started in is still going on.

If you say "Gino did PvP" without specifying when he did, the listener has to infer that information from context; whereas if you say "Gino has done PvP" without specifying when, that can potentially just mean "Gino has done PvP at least once in his life so far". (To be sure, it still can refer to a more-specific time period to be inferred from context; for example, if it's a response to "Has anyone played the game this week?", then it would mean "Gino has done PvP this week." But it doesn't have to.)
When Gino heard "Gino did PvP" with no specification of when, he had to infer (from context) a certain interpretation of what was meant. Since I don't have the context, I don't know what interpretation he inferred; but whatever it was, he apparently felt that it was misleading, so he felt the need to clarify that although he has done PvP at some point in his life, he didn't do . . . whatever it is that he thought was being implied.

I'm sure that Gino wanted to specify that he didn't play PvP mode for long and that it wasn't something that he put a lot of his time into. He wanted to express that he has done it on a single occasion at some time in the past.

Is it possible that when Gino heard "...did Pvp" he found it fitting to put in present perfect because as you've mentioned "whereas if you say 'Gino has done PvP' without specifying when, that can potentially just mean 'Gino has done PvP at least once in his life so far'". Both past simple and present perfect don't specify the time in this case so the past simple version could suggest that he was doing it for longer and that was something that he was engaged in longer. The present perfect version(without specifying the time) could mean that he's done it only once(which is what he mean).
